# How to post a data based to passed variable

Tags: php, mysql, cordova

I'm trying to insert a data into database with a name a table passed en parametre. I use phonegap,php, SOAP.
My database like this:

```
    function create_promo($nom_restaurant,$codeBarre,$designation,$dateDebut,$dateFin,$prix,$TVA,$photo){


      $db=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testf','root','');
      $req=$db->prepare("insert into'".$nom_restaurant."'values(:codeBarre,:designation,:dateDebut,:dateFin,:prix,:TVA,:photo)");
      $req->execute(array(':codeBarre'=>$codeBarre,':designation'=>$designation,':dateDebut'=>date("Y-m-d",strtotime($dateDebut)),':dateFin'=>date("Y-m-d",strtotime($dateFin)),':prix'=>$prix,':TVA'=>$TVA,':photo'=>$photo)); 
    return "promotion creer";

}
```

I get a name of table with ajax code:

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
     function getUrlVars() {
 var vars = [], hash;
 var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
 for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
 hash = hashes[i].split('=');
 vars.push(hash[0]);
 vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
 }
 return vars;
}
     var nom_restaurant = decodeURI(getUrlVars()["nom_restaurant"]);

     $("#new").append("<a href='ajout.html?nom_restaurant="+nom_restaurant+"'>"+"Nouvelle promotion"+"</a>");
```

In my script to insert database:

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
      function getUrlVars() {
 var vars = [], hash;
 var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
 for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
 hash = hashes[i].split('=');
 vars.push(hash[0]);
 vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
 }
 return vars;
}
 $("#insert").click(function(){
 var codeBarre=$("#codeBarre").val();
     var nom = decodeURI(getUrlVars()["nom_restaurant"]);
 $("#nom").val(nom); 
var nom_restaurant=$("#nom").val();
    var dataString="codeBarre="+codeBarre;

 alert (dataString);

 $.post({

            url:"http://192.168.1.15/fou/promoCre.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:{data:dataString,nom_restaurant:nom_restaurant},
            success: function(data){
            alert(data");},
            failure: function(errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }

});


    });

});
```

The name of table is getting but the insert doesn't work.

My php code:

```
  require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

 $client = new nusoap_client('http://localhost/fou/server.php');
$result=$client->call('create_promo',array('nom_restaurant'=>$_GET['nom_restaurant'],'codeBarre'=>$_POST['codeBarre'],'designation'=>$_POST['designation'],'dateDebut'=>$_POST['dateDebut'],'dateFin'=>$_POST['dateFin'],'prix'=>$_POST['prix'],'TVA'=>$_POST['TVA'],'photo'=>$_POST['photo']));
    print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

At least you should use `_POST` in PHP because you are using `POST` in ajax.

Comment: I use $_POST but no result.

Comment: @user6315007 Are you sure that variable nom_restaurant is ok before POST and POST happens? Check it with developer console.

Comment: I do an alert before POST, I get a variable nom_restaurant and an alert of dataString after POST,the data are right. I get an error indefined variable nom_restaurant on line  " $result=$client->call('create_promo',array('nom_restaurant'=>$_POST['nom_restaurant'],'codeBarre'=>$_POST['codeBarre'],'designation'=>$_POST['designation'],'dateDebut'=>$_POST['dateDebut'],'dateFin'=>$_POST['dateFin'],'prix'=>$_POST['prix'],'TVA'=>$_POST['TVA'],'photo'=>$_POST['photo'])); "

Comment: @user6315007 try printing all incoming variables in PHP with `print_R($_POST)` or `print_R($_REQUEST);`

Comment: I do print_R($_POST), I got a undefined value for all my data posted and Array()

Comment: @user6315007 okay, then it means that your data wasn't posted. Check your request via sniffer or browser's developer console.